# Image grid with autorescaling in HTML & CSS Only

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I have been trying to make a responsive auto rescaling image grid to display ads on our website. I used this as a reference - [W3Schools-ImageGridMaker](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_images_side_by_side)

Based on that, I tried 4days to come up with this piece of code.

```css
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

div.boxed {
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxed">

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UgPbxk2.jpg" alt="Shiva1"></a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ColLeDr.png" alt="Shiva2"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gVjcLg2.jpg" alt="Shiva3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/nxGxovl.png" alt="Shiva4"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This code is responsive, and on mobiles I got no problem because it looks neat by filling the full area. But if you look at it on a desktop, it injects empty space underneath some pics that doesn't fit the height. I am using bunch of URLs and can feed them as a list so that this 1280X200px area on desktop fills up neat with images that are of different sizes. I tried looking into freewall and a ton of other jsfiddles and pens but couldn't achieve on how to make the whitespace removed and make that particular box look good. Thanks.

Comment: I would use a more up to date tutorial - you should stop using floats, in the day of css3 there should be no need to abuse it on elements other than images (even probably no need to use it on images now), but your snippet doesn't show the behaviour you describe - on desktop I get no space under your images and the red box is flush around them all (but the images are blocked so they are all the same height on my browser)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The very first image has white space underneath it on a desktop. The red border is responsive to the largest height of an image inside the box.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to crop all your images to be the same height, if you are wanting a masonry effect, then you'll need to use a js plugin

Comment: I did resize the images to 400px height and yet they are not aligning to be of same height when I throw them inside the red box. Masonry effect? Let me see what that is. Thanks.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use object-fit - just set a height and width for each image (eg height 400px width 100%) and then use object fit cover - works like background size cover.  The only downside is you'll need a polyfill to make it work in ie - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comments - I would go with a flexbox solution that uses object-fit (with a polyfil for ie):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;   /* default value so optional - lines children in a row */
  flex-wrap: wrap;        /* allows children to wrap */
  justify-content: space-between; /* space children evenly over row */
}

.responsive {
  flex-basis: 25%;  /* makes the width 25% */
  
  /* if you don't want a fixed height image, I would use the padding top trick for aspect ratio divs */
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30%;
}

.responsive img {
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  object-fit:cover;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    padding-top: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/600" alt="Shiva3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/400" alt="Shiva3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/900" alt="Shiva3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://tnilive.com" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com'); window.open('https://www.yahoo.com');"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/400/700" alt="Shiva3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```